smartdiagram - control opacity of central node text
I am making a very simple bubble diagram with smartdiagram, but I notice that the text color of my central node is different from that of the other nodes, even if the same color is specified.
It seems like the text color of the central node is affected by this node's opacity, while the text in the other nodes isn't.
This is my MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{A589D9}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{95C753}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{35BEC1}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{F16D64}
\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{F3C746}
\definecolor{mypink}{HTML}{F371AF}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{666666}

\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\tikzset{bubble node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.25
    }
}
\tikzset{bubble center node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.25
    }
}

\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{
    distance text center bubble=0.5cm,
    bubble center node size=3cm,
    bubble node size=3cm,
    distance center/other bubbles=1cm,
    bubble center node font=\huge,
    bubble node font=\huge,
    bubble center node color=mypink,
    set color list = {mypurple, mygreen, myblue, myred, myyellow}
}%
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
    {\addfontfeature{Color=grey}team}\\{\addfontfeature{Color=grey}player},
    {\addfontfeature{Color=grey}fast}\\{\addfontfeature{Color=grey}learner},
    {\addfontfeature{Color=grey}motivated},
    {\addfontfeature{Color=grey}organized},
    {\addfontfeature{Color=grey}problem}\\{\addfontfeature{Color=grey}solver},
    {\addfontfeature{Color=grey}precise}%
}%
\end{document}

Which produces this:

Note the different color of the central node text, even when the same formatting as in the other nodes is passed... How can I correct this diagram so that the text color in all nodes is the same?

You can change the \pgfsetfillopacity for the text so all the text uses the same opacity:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{A589D9}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{95C753}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{35BEC1}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{F16D64}
\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{F3C746}
\definecolor{mypink}{HTML}{F371AF}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{666666}


\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\tikzset{bubble node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.25
    }
}
\tikzset{bubble center node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.25
    }
}

\begin{document}
\smartdiagramset{
    distance text center bubble=0.5cm,
    bubble center node size=3cm,
    bubble node size=3cm,
    distance center/other bubbles=1cm,
    bubble center node font=\huge\sffamily\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\color{gray},
    bubble node font=\huge\sffamily\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\color{gray},
    bubble center node color=mypink,
    set color list = {mypurple, mygreen, myblue, myred, myyellow}
}%
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
    team\\player,
    fast\\learner,
    motivated,
    organized,
    problem\\solver,
    precise%
}%
\end{document}



yes, this is it! thanks

@DaniCee You're welcome!
